# ANTLRworks creating interpreter from grammar

Tags: java, grammar, interpreter, antlrworks

Hey I have a quick question. I am using ANTLRworks to create an interpreter in Java from a set of grammar. I was going to write it out by hand but then realized I didn't have to because of antlrworks. I am getting this error though

T.g:9:23: label ID conflicts with token with same name

Is ANTLRworks the way to go when creating a interpreter from grammar. And do y'all see any error in my code?

I am trying to make ID one letter from a-z and not case sensitive. and to have white space in between every lexeme. THANK YOU

```
grammar T;

programs : ID WS compound_statement;

statement:       
if_statement|assignment_statement|while_statement|print_statement|compound_statement;

compound_statement: 'begin' statement_list 'end';

statement_list: statement|statement WS statement_list;  

if_statement:    'if' '(' boolean_expression ')' 'then' statement 'else' statement;

while_statement:    'while' boolean_expression 'do' statement;

assignment_statement:   ID = arithmetic_expression;

print_statement:    'print' ID;

boolean_expression: operand relative_op operand;

operand :   ID |INT;

relative_op:    '<'|'<='|'>'|'>='|'=='|'/=';

arithmetic_expression:  operand|operand WS arithmetic_op WS operand;

arithmetic_op:  '+'|'-'|'*'|'/';


ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_').
;

INT :   '0'..'9'+
;
WS  :   ( ' '
    | '\t'
    | '\r'
    | '\n'
    ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
;
```

and here is the grammar

```
<program> → program id <compound_statement>

<statement> → <if_statement> | <assignment_statement> | <while_statement> |     
<print_statement> | <compound_statement>

<compound_statement> → begin <statement_list> end

<statement_list> → <statement> | <statement> ; <statement_list>

<if_statement> → if <boolean_expression> then <statement> else <statement>

<while_statement> → while <boolean_expression> do <statement>

<assignment_statement> -> id := <arithmetic_expression>

<print_statement> → print id

<boolean_expression> → <operand> <relative_op> <operand>

<operand> → id | constant

<relative_op> → < | <= | > | >= | = | /=

<arithmetic_expression> → <operand> | <operand> <arithmetic_op> <operand>

<arithmetic_op> → + | - | * | /
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is ANTLRworks the way to go when creating a interpreter from grammar.

No.

ANTLRWorks can only be used to write your grammar and possibly test to see if it input properly (through its debugger or interpreter). It cannot be used to create an interpreter for the language you've written the grammar for. ANTLRWorks is just a fancy text-editor, nothing more.

> And do y'all see any error in my code?

As indicated by Treebranch: you didn't have quotes around the `=` sign in:

```
assignment_statement:   ID = arithmetic_expression;
```

making ANTLR "think" you wanted to assign the label `ID` to the parser rule `arithmetic_expression`, which is illegal: you can't have a label-name that is also the name of a rule (`ID`, in your case).

Answer (score -1):

Some possible issues in your code:

I think you want your ID tag to have a `+` regex so that it can be of length 1 or more, like so:

```
ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_')+
;
```

It also looks like you are missing quotes around your `=` sign:

```
assignment_statement:   ID '=' arithmetic_expression;
```

---

**EDIT**

Regarding your left recursion issue: ANTLR is very powerful because of the regex functionality. While an EBNF (like the one you have presented) may be limited in the way it can express things, ANTLR can be used to express certain grammar rules in a much simpler way. For instance, if you want to have a statement_list in your compound_statement, just use your *statement* rule with closure (`*`). Like so:

```
compound_statement: 'begin' statement* 'end';
```

Suddently, you can remove unnecessary rules like statement_list.

Comment: Thank you I fixed those now this popped up haha. TODO: run and send output to this console[12:26:51] error(211): T.g:6:15: [fatal] rule statement_list has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.
[12:26:51] error(211): X:\Users\Zahc\Documents\T.g:6:15: [fatal] rule statement_list has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.

Comment: So other than that my code seems to be fine? Sorry for the newby questions Im just new to this.

Comment: I haven't looked over your code in depth, I was just trying to suggest some ways to improve it as well as expose you to the expressiveness of ANTLR.

Comment: If you get a chance would you be able to? And this code will create an interpreter in java correct?

Comment: What I would suggest for you to do is to get the ANTLR eclipse plugin and bring your code over there, write a bunch of test cases for your grammer to parse, and then run them to see which parts of the grammar work as expected and which don't.

Comment: *Regarding your left recursion issue: ANTLR is very powerful because of the regex functionality*, err, what does left recursion have to do with *regex functionality*? And what exactly do you mean by *regex functionality*? Lexer rules are created using one ore more regular expressions, but I wouldn't go as far as calling ANTLR powerful because of that: all parser generators have this, it is not something that makes ANTLR stand out in certain areas.

Comment: Perhaps my statement was too general, the point I was trying to make is that without the closure (`*`), you will have to left factor your left recursive rules in a way that likely results in two rules. This is more complicated and reduces the understandability of your grammar. The regex features (`*`,`+`,`?`,etc.) are powerful because of their expressiveness (though you are right in saying it isn't exclusive to ANTLR).